# Php accessing Home directories

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions

I have a script and i d like to access to home directories of users in a Linux Environment.

Web root : /var/www/html/
And there are user directories such as : /home/john
/home/david 
etc.

There are files in users home directories. The permissions of user homes belong to the users. eg:
/home/david/file.txt user: david group: david

Is it possible to access these files with apache? I assume it s not because of the permission,

Is there a way around this ?

in other words, my php program under /var/www/html/index.php can acccess the files under /home/david/foo.txt

How can i get this done? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to have the users place the specific needed files into a `pub` directory, then `chmod 777` that directory.

If you want to access arbitrary files in the home directory, you have to run Apache as root, which is a *big* security risk. (While you could change the permissions of the home directory, this can mess up a lot of programs, in my experience.)

Comment: he can also set 777 to individual files and access them without changing groups etc.

Comment: If by *access* you mean *read*, 644 is enough -- no need to allow Apache to write to those files. Also make sure that all directories about the file have at least world execute permissions (711).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am a bit paranoid when it comes to these things, but in my opinion there is something conceptually wrong here:

A script, that is exposed to the web should never be given access to users' home directories. One reason for saying that is that a compromise of the web server might result in exposure of files in the home directories to anyone who can access the web server. Another reason is that files in the home directories are (at least to my understanding) a place where users keep more or less personal/private files that should not be available to other users. Otherwise they would have placed it in a public directory.

While I am not sure what your use case is, I suggest it might be better to use a different concept where Apache does not need access to the home directories of other users in the first place.